How can I check multiple `#ifdef` conditions using logical OR operator in ASM file?
I'm working on an assembly (ASM) file that needs to be conditionally compiled based on multiple #ifdef conditions. The compiler in use is CC-RL.

How can I check multiple #ifdef conditions using logical OR operator in ASM file?
Any insights, examples, or tips would be helpful

I'm expect that both ifdef and else parts should be successfully compiled, but I'm getting error as  for the variables in else part.
#if defined( TYPE00_SOFT_Z1A ) || defined( TYPE01_SOFT_Z2A ) 
CNLT_CNFG .EQU 0x01 
FCC_CNLT_DATA .EQU 0xFC 
#else 
CNLT_CNFG .EQU 0x00 
FCC_CNLT_DATA .EQU 0xFD 
#endif


Instead of #ifdef sym and #ifndef sym, you can use #if defined(sym) and #if !defined(sym).  Then you can combine them with || and &&, e.g. #if defined(sym1) && !defined(sym2).

Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Are you sure it is #if and not $if (etc for other control instructions)? CC-RL docs say "#" is a whole-line comment and "$" is for control instructions.

@AndreyTurkin That's a good point.  From the question, I had assumed it was using a cpp-type preprocessor, but if not, then that would explain the error message (i.e., the the # lines are being treated as comment lines).

Do you actually pass your code through the preprocessor?

If I use $if it is showing Label description is incorrect.

I'm not sure if $if is case-insensitive (it is defined by docs to be in caps just like all the others, i.e. "$IF"). And I also doubt there is a defined() operator in this assembly language so this whole train of thought may be moot...

Edit the question to provide a [mre]. That imcludes the exact assemble/compile/build command(s) used and an exact copy of the output, including error messages.

How to give check multiple parameters with logical OR in a single if condition in asm file using c
